# Populate participants reading a json file in hyperledger

Tags: javascript, json, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

i'm trying to create a transaction to automatically populate the participants of my network.

I have few experience with Javascript and Json, but my idea is to read an external json file to populate the participants.

Can someone show me how can i read the json file with javascript, in order to retrieve the informations?

Thanks

Comment: Where is this json file located? Is it in a filesystem, served over an API?

Comment: For now, the json is a file located in the same folder of my javascript file.

Comment: I assume you are using `composer`. In that case you cannot read external files directly. You have 2 options, either store the json in a function you can call only once. Think of it like a bootstrap or init function, or store the json in a separate file on your server and submit it as part of a transaction. I personally prefer the second option since you can also handle identity issuing at the same time.

Comment: Yes, i'm using composer but honestly i'm trying to understand the Fabric API to work directly on it. Thank you for the advices.